# Node.js - HTTP get through Squid proxy authorization issue

Tags: node.js, squid

I am trying to make a simple request using http.get.  But I need to make this request through Squid proxy.  Here's my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var host = "proxy_host";
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

var options = {
  host: host,
  port: 3128,
  path: "http://www.google.com",
  authorization: auth,
  headers: {
    Host: 'www.google.com'
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
});

req.end();
```

My username and password is correct according to the ops team that set up the proxy.  The problem is that I keep getting a 407 - authorization required status coming back.

Is there something wrong with the way I am making the request? Or does Squid proxy need to be configured?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to take al https://stackoverflow.com/a/67952667/13251578

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should include `auth` in the `headers` section of `options`:

```
var options = {
  host: host,
  port: 3128,
  path: "http://www.google.com",
  headers: {
    'Proxy-Authorization': auth,
    Host: 'www.google.com'
  }
};
```

Comment: Man, I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks.  Squid wasn't looking for the `Authorization` header, though.  It looks for `'Proxy-Authorization'`

Comment: Guys, you saved my day! Agree with @Anthony it worked for me with 'Proxy-Authorization'. Thanks!