# Why do I get 407 status code when I send Node.js http request via cntlm proxy?

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy

I get this console output. My code is very simple. My company use Squid ntlm proxy, so I use cntlm proxy to make things easier. However, I can't use cntlm proxy to make node apps. I need help.

```
All is well!
You hit http.get
407
Proxy Authentication Required
{ server: 'squid/4.6',
  'mime-version': '1.0',
  date: 'Sat, 12 Jun 2021 14:19:33 GMT',
  'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '3490',
  'x-squid-error': 'ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0',
  vary: 'Accept-Language',
  'content-language': 'en',
  'x-cache': 'MISS from centry',
  'x-cache-lookup': 'NONE from centry:3128',
  via: '1.1 centry (squid/4.6)',
  connection: 'close',
  'proxy-authenticate': 'Basic realm="Cntlm for parent"' }
```

my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

app.get("/get", function(req,res){

var opts = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3128,
    path: "http://www.google.com:80",
  };

  var req = http.get(opts, function(res) {
      
    console.log("You hit http.get");
    
    console.log(res.statusCode);
    console.log(res.statusMessage);
    console.log(res.headers);
  });

})



app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("All is well!");
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why is the path "http://www.google.com:80"?

Comment: I am just trying to get 200 OK code :D.

Answer (score 1):

I found solutions after 12 hours !!

```
var opts = {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 3128,
        path: "http://url.com",

       headers: {
        'Connection'       : 'keep-alive',
        }
        
      };
```

If you change path to "http://google.com", you get 301 code (Moved Permanently). Because google.com is redirecting somehow.

All point is at

```
headers: {
            'Connection'       : 'keep-alive',
            }
```